# Duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config "

Tags: android, android-resources

I really do now know why I got this `error` and how can I solve it.
Actually I am not sure What I did right before I got this `error`.

> Error Msg:
>   /Users/hyun/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.arr/25699caf34fef6313d6ec32013a1a117f/res/values/values.xml
>   error:duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config".
>   error: resource previously defined here
>
> /Users/hyun/Desktop/Laftel-Android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDbugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
>   duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ".
>   resource previously defined here.
>
> Java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:com.android.tools.appt2.Aapt2Exception:AAPT2 error: check for details Execution failed for task ':app::mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: java.utilconcurrentExcutionException:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception : AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: started to have this error today out of nowhere, I do not know what happened so that this occurs, have you managed to find the solution? I'm looking all day and nothing.

Comment: YES!
First if you are using typeset library, abandon this library.
Second 
- complieSdkVersion 27
- buildTollsVersion 27.0.2
- make all com.android.support library to 27.0.2

I hope you solve problem

Comment: the error continues here: /

Comment: 27.0.2 version has some bugs with CollapsingToolbarLayout, that's why i need to use 25.4.0. any help?

Comment: Resolved by Cleaning and Rebuilding! ☺

Answer (score 47):

It may the concept that makes conflicts with the logic that we have previously used for apply Custom fonts.

**Previously**

We have used below code for creating the custom attribute for the font.

```
    <declare-styleable name="CustomFont">
        <attr name="font" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

**What I change**

In my case, this was the issue and I have resolved it by renaming the attr name

```
    <declare-styleable name="CustomFont">
        <attr name="fontName" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

This same thing may apply if you are using any third party library or Custom View with **"font"** property

As per suggestion by [reverie_ss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6747251/reverie-ss) Please  Check your **res->values->attrs.xml**

Comment: Incase anyone is unable to find it,
Check your res->values->attrs.xml

Comment: This pointed me to the right direction. I also had to update Java code such as R.styleable.com_my_app_font to .....fontName.

Comment: how to solve custom library attribute that are take as aar

Answer (score 41):

support library 26 added font attribute to XML elements like TextView, etc. In my case, I was using a library with custom views and a custom attribute `app:font`, so they collided. After renaming the library attribute to something else (textFont), all went good again. So, are you using a custom 'font' attribute somewhere? Did you update Gradle to supportLibrary 26 or 27 recently? If you can't override the attribute name, try rolling back to 25

Comment: How did you rename the library attribute?  Did you change the source of the library

Comment: Yes, it was a private library developed by ourserlves, so we had complete access to the code.

Answer (score 23):

After migrating to AndroidX my error message was

`error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/progress' with config ''`

and I had a custom attribute defined for a custom view as the following:

```
<declare-styleable name="ProductionProgressItemView">
    <attr name="progressTitle" format="string"/>
    <attr name="progress" format="string"/>
    <attr name="progressPercent" format="integer"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

renaming progress to `progressValue` fixed the issue.

Comment: had the exact same problem, you just made my life easier

Answer (score 6):

i updated my android-X libraries to newer versions and i got this type of error in `styles.xml`

```
error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/progress' with config ''
```

this was my previous code there

```
<declare-styleable name="CircleProgressBar">
    <attr name="min" format="integer" />
    <attr name="max" format="integer" />
    <attr name="progress" format="integer" />
    <attr name="progressbarColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="progressBarThickness" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

i changed the `progress` attribute value by refactoring it to `progressValue` like below.

```
<declare-styleable name="CircleProgressBar">
    <attr name="min" format="integer" />
    <attr name="max" format="integer" />
    <attr name="progressValue" format="integer" />
    <attr name="progressbarColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="progressBarThickness" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem...

**My PROBLEM** : I used same attribute name (ex. `editable`) in tow xml : `attr_1.xml` and `attr_2.xml`

**attr_1.xml :**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomContainerEditText">
        <attr name="android:text" format="string" />
        <attr name="editable" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**attr_2.xml :**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomContainerEditText">
        <attr name="editable" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**SOLUTION** :
(Short Answer) I just **remove** `format="String"` from one of xml attribute file (like `attr_2.xml`) and my problem fixed.

**attr_2.xml :**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomContainerEditText">
        <attr name="editable" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Did not work for me. I have two libraries using the same attr name. Removed the format attribute in one of them. The compiler still gives the error of the question.

Comment: It works, thanks. But sadly, that kind of "problems" and especially that kind of solutions remind me of it how rubish system Android is.

Answer (score 3):

repeat in
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'

I remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I am using supporting library 27.1.1 and definitely targetSDKVersion is 27. There was a conflict with other library in my case It was google play services which also adds supporting library but with older version so there are two libraries which creates issue.

Add this in project level build.gradle file

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found this here [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14020)

Comment: What does this solution do?

Comment: As far as my understanding it uses "26.1.0" support library version for all dependencies which use support libraries, when you are targeting SDK version 27 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

If you are migrating to androidx, try putting the below code in gradle.properties, if this file doesn't exist inside your project directory create one and put the below lines. This solved

`Duplicate value for resource 'attr/.*' with config ''`

error in my case

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Comment: Looks like error is still occurring in my case: **AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/progress' with config**

Answer (score 1):

try compileSdkVersion 25, then it will be all ok.
support library 26 added font attribute to xml elements like TextView, etc, so if you want to use sdkversion 26 then you need to renaming the library attribute to something else (textFont), all went good again

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.
In my case I just had

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

and I added

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

and  it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case : **error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/mode' with config ''**

It was directly related to the following library

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

I had to rename my **declare-styleable** which had a name as **mode** to something such as **custom_mode**. It then fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

In My case, textColor and text_background_color are creating the problem but after adding the format It's working fine
before adding format

```
<declare-styleable name="OtpView">
    <attr name="android:inputType">number</attr>
    <attr name="textColor"/>
    <attr name="OtpView_android_textColor" />
    <attr name="text_background_color"/>
    <!--<attr name="text_background_color" format="color">?back_icon_color</attr>-->
    <attr name="otp" format="string" />
    <attr name="lineColor" format="reference|color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

after adding the format to textColor and text_beckground_color property it get solved

```
<declare-styleable name="OtpView">
    <attr name="android:inputType">number</attr>
    <attr name="textColor" format="string"/>
    <attr name="OtpView_android_textColor" />
    <attr name="text_background_color" format="string"/>
    <!--<attr name="text_background_color" format="color">?back_icon_color</attr>-->
    <attr name="otp" format="string" />
    <attr name="lineColor" format="reference|color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep reducing the version of the dependency mentioned in the path 
In your case its:   */Users/hyun/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/**appcompat-v7-27.0.1**.arr/25699caf34fef6313d6ec32013a1a117f/res/values/values.xml* 
 So reducing the version number for **appcompat-v7-27.0.1** to **27.0.0** might work. 
If it doesn't work then keep on reducing the version number and re-build the project each time until it works.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```