# Gradle Error : Duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config " solutions not working

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to **create circular-shaped buttons** for my first android app.

For that, I added the library as
`compile 'com.cuboid:cuboidcirclebutton:1.0.5'` in circlebutton/app/build.gradle

As I sync, I get errors. below is the log

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\Amninder\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\2d55d8c33dae479e599960c08d012b17\res\values\values.xml
Error:(246, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ''.
Error:(246, 5) error: resource previously defined here.

C:\Users\Amninder\AndroidStudioProjects\circlebutton\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Error:(254) duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ''.

Error:(240) resource previously defined here.

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

 Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED in 19s
Information:6 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console`
```

Below is a list of things I tried and failed.

1.removing attr/font on line 254 > doing save all > clean project > rebuild project.

2. I was inspired by this youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF0m_PG111g so checked in its comments section. First, the comment was the same error. So, check this  [guy's blog](http://artvk.blogspot.com/2017/11/error736-duplicate-value-for-resource.html). So I got to know the error was because of adding the library only. So I searched on google for - how to add a custom library in android [referred to this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20to%20add%20custom%20library%20in%20android%20studio&rlz=1C1NHXL_enIN729IN729&oq=how%20to%20add%20custom%20libaries%20in%20androi&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.10866j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). opened it and there was no info. regarding the error, I am facing.
3. Saw another link on the video, from StackOverflow this time.[here is the link](http://%20EDMT%20Dev%20EDMT%20Dev%203%20weeks%20ago%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668526/duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-font-with-config). He says "After renaming the library attribute to something else (text font), all went good again." I also tried renaming the attr/font to attr/1txtfont but changes were not reflected at all.

Can anyone here please help me out on this?

Answer (score 6):

You're using support library **version 26** which defines attribute `attr/font` and the library defines the same attribute, this is what causes the error.

So you either use support library **version < 26**, for example: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1`. Or the library owner rename the attribute

Comment: Can we use support lib **28**?

Comment: don't really know, you can try it and see if you get the same error or not

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much for your valuable insight y.allam. For any person who faces such an error. Below are the elaborated changes.

In your file `build.gradle`, change `compileSdkVersion` to 25 , `targetSdkVersion` to 25

[image: solution part 1] .

Now in the same file, as sorted out by y.allam, change the SDK version to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1`.

[[image: solution part 22]