# Android Resource Compilation failed due to values.xml in new project

Tags: java, android

I created a new project using Android Studio and in the progress of the first synchronization it threw the following Error:

I have updated the IDE and all included modules / sdk's, but so far nothing has helped. 
I'm not able to find a problem in the references values.xml file.

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  /AndroidStudioProjects/testproject/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1050: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
/AndroidStudioProjects/testproject/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1050: error: resource previously defined here.

Command: /.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/32cdec39e96edfdbcf3c18e04fb62256/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 compile --legacy \
        -o \
        /AndroidStudioProjects/testproject/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
        /AndroidStudioProjects/testproject/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
```

I'd be very grateful for any insights and help.

Edit: The suggested duplicate was only resolved by using an old sdk (25), the current one used by my project is 28 and downgrading by 3 versions is not an adequate solution from my point of view.

2nd Update: Even changing compileSdkVersion down to 25 and even 23, as suggested in the possible duplicate, did not help. Still got the same error.

Comment: clean your project and then run it.

Comment: What is this error exactly you don't understand?

Comment: Update: Cleaning the project did not help. Still throws the same error.

To elaborate on the core of the problem: I installed Android Studio and wanted to make a test project. Have added nothing to the automatically generated empty activity, changed nothing on the project overall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Error : Duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config " solutions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988489/gradle-error-duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-font-with-config-solutions)