# While updating compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion to 26 - duplicate value for resource 'attr/fontFamily' with config

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-gradle-3.0, android-buildconfig

I'm updating my apps compile & target SDK version from 23 to 26 (Android 8.0). But after update, getting following error:

**error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/fontFamily' with config '.**

Having following support libraries now in gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Please don't suggest to downgrade targetSdkVersion to 25. Don't suggest this question as well: [Duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668526/duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-font-with-config)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the issue was of an older dependency used in app to use **RobotoTextView**. I've been able to resolve this issue by updating this library.

from:

```
implementation 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.5.0'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:4.0.0'
```