# How to fix an error while upgrading the targetSdkVersion from version 25 to 27?

Tags: java, android, target-sdk

As play store doesn't provide me the permission to upload one apk with a **targetSdkVersion** of 25. So, I upgraded my **targetSdkVersion** from 25 to 27 and downloaded the all necessary libraries by adding dependencies.

I am provided below the entire build.gradle file code with the changes I made-

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')




implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.whinc:ratingbar:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.3'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
implementation 'com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.4'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'


}
```

But after syncing I am getting the following errors-

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
>   C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\ad0857f7c335bc06a588407b354d6c8b\res\values\values.xml
>
> Error:(251, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ''.
>
> Error:(251, 5) error: resource previously defined here.
>
> K:\my-app\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
>
> Error:(484) duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ''.
>
> Error:(459) resource previously defined here.
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 9s
>   Information:6 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

As I can't rollback back to targetSdkVersion 25.Please suggest me any solution to solve this issue and upgrade targetSdkVersion to 27.

Comment: I am getting same error and not able to sort out this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) you need to use the correct build-tools, which are version `27.0.3`. while I merely wonder why you updated to API `27` instead of the current API `28`; this would use build-tools version `28.0.3`.

b) and you have to fix these invalid resources; one duplicate `attr/font` clashes with `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0`. this comes from any occurrence of `<attr name="font" format="string"/>` in the project's XML, which has to be removed or renamed.

c) adding the `buildscript` (most likely twice) into the module-level `build.gradle` is non-sense. `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` also exists twice; this `build.gradle` is a mess.

Comment: @S.M.Asif please consider accepting the answer, when it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668526/duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-font-with-config)

TLDR Try renaming the library attribute to something else (textFont) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: it's a duplicate, just didn't vote to close because there are more issues than just this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

to the project-level build.gradle in dependencies section ( maybe you need to upgrade gradle to 4.6 in gradle-wrapper-properties ) :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

And increase buildToolsVersion to '28.0.3' in app-level build.gradle.
Then clean project or do './gradlew clean' in terminal in your project directory ( possible with android studio terminal ).

Comment: After doing all these I am getting following error-

` What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed

@ Ali Khoshraftar

Comment: which version of android studio you are using ?

Comment: Android studio 3.0.1 @Ali Khoshraftar

Comment: it's too old , install android studio 3.2.1 , it will fix