# Android resource compilation failed aapt2

Tags: android, aapt2

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  D:\MyApplication3\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:400: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
D:\MyApplication3\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:400: error: resource previously defined here.

Command: C:\Users\mishr\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\c3b69b71879b5e4816ee3d81c1fe5bb9\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\MyApplication3\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        D:\MyApplication3\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668526/duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-font-with-config

Comment: I was facing the same issue and migrating to androidx solved my problem.