# how to solve duplicate value for resource 'attr/max_value' with config i already try stackover answer but it not working

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, duplicates

app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3648: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/max_value' with config ''.

app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3648: error: resource previously defined here.

/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml  when i change max_value it automatically change again previous name and give me same error

**gradle file**

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'

implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.8'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.kevalpatel2106:ruler-picker:1.0'

implementation 'com.alex-zaitsev:meternumberpicker:1.0.4'
implementation 'net.soulwolf.widget:materialRadio:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.shinelw.colorarcprogressbar:library:1.0.3'
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Show your research, including any other SO Q&A you have read. Context is everything: tell us what you are doing and show the exact results you get as copyable, formatted, searchable text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668526/duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-font-with-config.    Already try this question and similar questions I found that two library provide same max_values but i don't now how to find these library which are providing same nax_values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668526/duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-font-with-config)

Comment: This not working for me#jdv

Comment: Then tell us _how_ it is not working for you. Show your research as I asked in my first comment. How is the linked Q&A _not_ working? What steps have you taken to solve this? Don't use comments to update the question. That is what the [edit] button is for.