# AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/type' with config ''. AAPT: error: resource previously defined here

Tags: java, android

I have been debugging for 3 days but still couldn't resolve it. It would make my day if anyone of you have some idea on the source of the problem and how I might fix it? forgive me I don't know any better ways to paste the error message.

Error log:

> Cause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>   compilation failed
>       /Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fa74de4132a623c0b9e0baae873e9df0/res/values/values.xml:3:5-130:
>   AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/type' with config ''.
>
> /Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fa74de4132a623c0b9e0baae873e9df0/res/values/values.xml:3:5-130:
>   AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

Comment: check this: [rename attr name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775778/10711373)
Hope to solve your problem.

Comment: @reyhane i check all the name of the value, i could not found any duplicate name. Any other suggestion?

Comment: It's not just the duplicity of the name. Some names have already been booked. for example, you should change `progress` to `progressValue`

Comment: @reyhane i have done changes in most of the name, but still the error persist. Do you have any suggestion, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I removed one of the library I used, and the problem was gone. I guess it was the library.