# AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/progress' with config ''

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting the issue when rebuild project.
Tried to clean and Invalidate cache/ restart nothing works.

```
Android resource compilation failed
C:\Users\Sandeep Kumar\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f4aaccbd354d0bc3666bd4b394d746c1\library-1.2\res\values\values.xml:7:5-21:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/progress' with config ''.

C:\Users\Sandeep Kumar\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f4aaccbd354d0bc3666bd4b394d746c1\library-1.2\res\values\values.xml:7:5-21:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
```

Code from  file values.xml - Read Only file

```
<resources>
    <eat-comment />
    <declare-styleable name="NumberProgressBar">
        <attr name="progress" format="integer" />
        <attr name="max" format="integer" />
        <attr name="progress_unreached_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="progress_reached_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="progress_reached_bar_height" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="progress_unreached_bar_height" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="progress_text_size" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="progress_text_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="progress_text_offset" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="progress_text_visibility" format="enum">
            <enum name="visible" value="0" />
            <enum name="invisible" value="1" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="Themes">
        <attr name="numberProgressBarStyle" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>

    <eat-comment />

    <string name="app_name">AndroidNumberProgressBar</string>

    <eat-comment />

    <style name="NumberProgressBar_Beauty_Red">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="max">100</item>
        <item name="progress">0</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_color">#CCCCCC</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_color">#FF3D7F</item>
        <item name="progress_text_size">10sp</item>
        <item name="progress_text_color">#FF3D7F</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_bar_height">1.5dp</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_bar_height">0.75dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NumberProgressBar_Default">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="max">100</item>
        <item name="progress">0</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_color">#CCCCCC</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_color">#3498DB</item>
        <item name="progress_text_size">10sp</item>
        <item name="progress_text_color">#3498DB</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_bar_height">1.5dp</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_bar_height">0.75dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NumberProgressBar_Funny_Orange">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="max">100</item>
        <item name="progress">0</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_color">#CCCCCC</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_color">#FF530D</item>
        <item name="progress_text_size">10sp</item>
        <item name="progress_text_color">#FF530D</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_bar_height">1.5dp</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_bar_height">0.75dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NumberProgressBar_Grace_Yellow">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="max">100</item>
        <item name="progress">0</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_color">#CCCCCC</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_color">#FFC73B</item>
        <item name="progress_text_size">10sp</item>
        <item name="progress_text_color">#FFC73B</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_bar_height">1.5dp</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_bar_height">0.75dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NumberProgressBar_Passing_Green">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="max">100</item>
        <item name="progress">0</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_color">#CCCCCC</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_color">#70A800</item>
        <item name="progress_text_size">10sp</item>
        <item name="progress_text_color">#70A800</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_bar_height">1.5dp</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_bar_height">0.75dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NumberProgressBar_Relax_Blue">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="max">100</item>
        <item name="progress">0</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_color">#CCCCCC</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_color">#6DBCDB</item>
        <item name="progress_text_size">10sp</item>
        <item name="progress_text_color">#6DBCDB</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_bar_height">1.5dp</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_bar_height">0.75dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NumberProgressBar_Twinkle_Night">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="max">100</item>
        <item name="progress">0</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_color">#CCCCCC</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_color">#ECF0F1</item>
        <item name="progress_text_size">10sp</item>
        <item name="progress_text_color">#ECF0F1</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_bar_height">1.5dp</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_bar_height">0.75dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NumberProgressBar_Warning_Red">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="max">100</item>
        <item name="progress">0</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_color">#CCCCCC</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_color">#E74C3C</item>
        <item name="progress_text_size">10sp</item>
        <item name="progress_text_color">#E74C3C</item>
        <item name="progress_reached_bar_height">1.5dp</item>
        <item name="progress_unreached_bar_height">0.75dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and the issue with code

```
    <declare-styleable name="NumberProgressBar">
        <attr name="progress" format="integer" />
        <attr name="max" format="integer" />
        <attr name="progress_unreached_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="progress_reached_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="progress_reached_bar_height" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="progress_unreached_bar_height" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="progress_text_size" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="progress_text_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="progress_text_offset" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="progress_text_visibility" format="enum">
            <enum name="visible" value="0" />
            <enum name="invisible" value="1" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
```

Here more details in this Run build

```
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:247)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:159)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkerExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:285)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:115)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.access$000(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker$2.run(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:159)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    ... 127 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
C:\Users\Sandeep Kumar\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f4aaccbd354d0bc3666bd4b394d746c1\library-1.2\res\values\values.xml:7:5-21:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/progress' with config ''.

C:\Users\Sandeep Kumar\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f4aaccbd354d0bc3666bd4b394d746c1\library-1.2\res\values\values.xml:7:5-21:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create(Aapt2Exception.kt:45)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create$default(Aapt2Exception.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:195)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteCompileException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:87)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileRunnable.kt:40)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileRunnable.kt:29)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:66)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:64)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable.run(Aapt2CompileRunnable.kt:35)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:39)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:55)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: The problem is in the attribute name `progress`. Change it to something else and try to build the project once again. For more please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53278825/5180017)

Comment: I tried to change in this line  <attr name="progress" format="integer" />but nothing happens @Shashanth

Comment: Can you [edit] and post the updated code here? If not me, fellow SO users try to answer your question.

Comment: @Shashanth  Edited the post and added file code

Comment: Why didn't you change the line `<attr name="progress" format="integer" />`? Change it to something like `<attr name="progressValue" format="integer" />`. And try again.

Comment: I tried it but not able to do because it reset file on rebuild to default. It's read only file. That's why.. File path seems to be a cache version @Shashanth

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I update my constraintLayoutVersion from 1.1.3 to 2.0.0-beta4, Because in new ConstraintLayoutVersion It has new attr property named 'progress' and you(your project libraries) shouldn't have made any attr with the same name

in your code styles search for `<attr name="progress" format="" />` and rename 'progress' to 'yourCustomTextProgress' or if you use any progress library check for updates, It should be work