# Duplicate value for resource 'attr/counterTextColor' with config 'DEFAULT'

Tags: android, gradle, build

This error returns to me when I try to run the project on the device

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming couterTextColor should fix the problem .

for more details

[Duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668526/duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-font-with-config)